# NetBeans cursor stuck scroll lock mode

Tags: scroll, netbeans-8

I have a strange problem in my NetBeans. I opened a project I created in the past.  The project is compiling and running well. When I try to move around in the source files, the cursor is stuck in-place and the entire file is moving.

I checked and the scroll lock is not pressed - other applications are normal. The files are not read only, I can edit them. I am not using any kind of version control which might be locking me.

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

turned out to be because I set the keyboard mapping to "VS". I flipped it back to "NetBeans" and just modified what I wanted, and it's OK again.